# Advanced tracing and debugging JavaScript with DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am tracing an extensive and minified JS script on a live website and I am wondering, if there is perhaps a better way to find pieces of information that I am looking for, than stepping through the code or traversing call stacks.

Is there a way to set a breakpoint when a certain string or integer value is assigned to **any** variable?

This would help me find the section of the script that I wish to debug, without having to know the variable name.

Comment: Minified scripts aren't meant to be debugged on their own. When developing a site, there should be a development version, which uses non-minified scripts or source maps (`.map`), that would be used for debugging.

Comment: I understand that, but is there such functionality in the DevTools debugger or not?

Comment: You want Watchpoints -> https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/javascript/reference/#watch

Comment: @CBroe Thanks, I saw that, but I am not sure how to use it when I don't know the variable name, only value. Can it even work like that?

Comment: No, I don't think you can do _that_. (It would have to "watch" _all_ variables all the time, even the ones not coming from the script itself, but also pre-existing ones.)

Comment: I see, how about any 3rd party software that would hook into CDP? There should be something already made for JS debugging and reversing toolbox.